# How to Update Column based on another table column value

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have two data tables

table

```
id  isfav
---------
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1

favtable id 
-----------    
  2    true
  3    false
```

So I want to update the table1 column `isFav` to 0 if the ids exist in `FavTable` with false.

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Any()` to search in other entities.

```
var db = new YourDbContext();
var favtable = db.favtable.ToList();

//Find them:
var result = db.Table1.Where(t => favtable.Any(f => f.id == t.id && !f.isfav));

//result should be 3.
```

.NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BmaqN5

Comment: Is there any other way without datacontext?

Comment: DataContext is just an example. The code above should work once you get two lists running. Can you try it and see if it helps your case?